# How can initialize Fancybox into WordPress with a separate .js file properly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I did a search and found this method [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302588/how-can-i-integrate-fancybox-3-in-wordpress-properly?newreg=66257b211039443eba1b7859a41c22f2) using `wp_add_inline_script`. And it works.

But what if I wanted to keep my initialization script into an other .js file? That's what I wanted at first. How I can I load correctly?
I tried this but the loading of my `init-fancybox` must be too early because I get an error.

(my `init-fancybox` script is not the problem because it works when it is loaded correctly  using `wp_add_inline_script`)

```
function fancybox_enqueues() { 

    wp_register_script( 'fancybox', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js' ), array('jquery'), '3.5.7', true);
    wp_register_script( 'init-fancybox', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/init-fancybox.js' ), array('jquery','fancybox'), '1.0', true);
    wp_register_style( 'fancybox-css', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css' ), '1.0');

    if ( is_singular( 'item' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox' );
        wp_enqueue_script ('init-fancybox');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fancybox-css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fancybox_enqueues');
```

Here is the error I get `TypeError: $ is not a function`

And here is the **init-fancybox.js**

```
$('[data-fancybox="single-item__gallery"]').fancybox({
    buttons : [ 
        "zoom",
        "share",
        //"slideShow",
        "fullScreen",
        //"download",
        "thumbs",
        "close"
    ],
    thumbs : {
      autoStart : false
    }
  });
```

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems jQuery is not loaded by the time your code is running. Try adding the following function around it to make sure jQuery exists before your code runs:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  // Your function goes here:
  $('[data-fancybox="single-item__gallery"]').fancybox({
    buttons: [
      "zoom",
      "share",
      //"slideShow",
      "fullScreen",
      //"download",
      "thumbs",
      "close"
    ],
    thumbs: {
      autoStart: false
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I tried with `$(document).ready(function() {});` around my function but it doesn't work yet unfortunately. I get the same error. Shouldn't jQuery itself be ready for this function to work as well?
What is weird is that jQuery is loaded fast enough for `jquery.fancybox.min.js` to work but not `init-fancybox.js`. Besides, where did you expect me to write the script linking to jQuery? It shouldn't be needed as I already enqueued it right?

Comment: Please try the same using jQuery(document).ready(function($){});
I think in Wordpress, jQuery is registered as "jQuery" in global scope, not as "$".